# How to do a 301 regex redirect with IIS7

Tags: iis-7, redirect, .net, windows

How can I do a 301 redirect with this pattern: /([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$) in my .NET solution to redirect /en/solutions/exemple to /en/exemple in my web.config file

PS:I am new to .NET and IIS that's why I am asking

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rules>
    <rule name="regex redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\/([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?$)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/en/solutions/exemple"
           redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

Thanks